# Spring boot JPARepository native Query

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am using springboot JPAREPOSITORY and SQL server as db and getting the following exception while using JPARepository."org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query".
JPARepository method like findAll() works fine. Facing issue when I am using any native query.

```
 @Entity
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "ABC_Data")

    public class WeeklyActualESBDao
    {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "ESB_ACTUALSDATA_ID")
    private Integer    actualsId;
    
    
    
        @Column(name = "division")
        private Integer    division;
    
        @Column(name = "familyTreeLevel")
        private String     familyTreeLevel;
    
        @Column(name = "departmentCode")
        private Integer    departmentCode;
    
        @Column(name = "year")
        private Integer    year;
    
        @Column(name = "period")
        private Integer    period;
    
        @Column(name = "week_of_period")
        private Integer    weekOfPeriod;
    
        @Column(name = "net_sales")
        private BigDecimal netSales       = new BigDecimal(0);
    
        @Column(name = "delivered_gross")
        private BigDecimal deliveredGross = new BigDecimal(0);
    
        @Column(name = "units")
        private Integer    units;
    }

@Query(value = "SELECT  ADYEAR , ADPERIOD, ADWEEK "
        + " FROM "
        + " ESB_ACTUALS_DATA where  ADYEAR = :year", nativeQuery = true)
    List<WeeklyActualESBDao> getSales(@Param("year") Integer year);
```

[image: Error console]

Comment: The native query refers to a table called `ESB_ACTUALS_DATA`, but the error message references `ESB_ACTUALSDATA_ID`.  Are you sure that the code executing is what you have included in the question?

Comment: the error message which u have pasted is telling that the value which u have given in the `actualsId` is not correct so plz check that first and then execute the code

Comment: Datatype of columns in DB..

ESB_Actuals_Data_ID ( bigint autoincrement) division ( int) familyTreeLevel ( char 64) departmentCode( int) year ( int ) period ( int ) weekOfPeriod( int) netsales ( numeric 30,10 ) etc. And the table name is ESB_ACTUALS_DATA. It is giving the error for the column which I used @Id. In my case it is ESB_ACTUALSDATA_ID. Kindly help with this as I am stuck.In my entity class table name is ESB_ACTUALS_DATA. by mistake I wrote the ABC_DATA.

Comment: findAll() and other jparepository built in method works fine but only  problem with nativequery. If anyone has any idea. Kindly let me know.I have checked the column name all are same as database column. Just wanted to ask I ran the database query manually without using flyway script.Can that be the problem?